# How to substring from a link at specific character?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I don't know whats the proplem with it? I tried to solve it but I didn't get any result!!

my browser link

```
http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx?id=2
```

and the code is

```
string uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            int num1 = uri.IndexOf('=');
            int num2=uri.Length-1;

            string ID = uri.Substring(num1,num2);
```

The error says :

Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

[image]
so, what is wrong with it ?!

Comment: num2 is HOW MANY CHARS TO TAKE. not the last index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substring is not the way to do what it appears you are trying to do... which is to get the value of the query string parameter `id`.

You get a query string parameter like:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

And if your `id` is actually an `int`, you could do something like:

```
int realId = 0;
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
if (Int32.TryParse(id, out realId))
{
    //do something with realId    
}
```

Comment: @F505, agreed. which is why I upvoted this answer (it is better than mine), perhaps you should do the same before marking it as your answer?

Answer (score 5):

If you're just trying to isolate the parameter:

```
string ID = uri.Substring(num1);
```

(David Pilkington's explanation of why it fails is correct.)

Comment: ... or `num1+1` assuming he doesn't want the `=`, and also assuming there will never be another parameter... and also assuming that there will always be at least one parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the second parameter is the length of the substring that you are looking for and that `num2` is much too large for the operation to work

change the second parameter to    `uri.Length - num1`

The alternative is that you do not include a second parameter. In this case, take the substring from the index that you provide until the end of the string.

Here, have a read through the MSDN documentation on the method and you will see where you went wrong

[String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your best bet is

```
uri.Substring(uri.IndexOf('=')+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

An Uri already provides methods for searching, no need to do that yourself:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx?id=2");
Console.WriteLine(uri.Query.Split('=')[1]);
```

Note, in your actual (production) code you may want to include some error checking to verifiy that the query part contains "id".